# JSP servlet include output tuncated

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to include the response from a servlet in a jsp page using:

```
<li><jsp:include page="/icr/TasksServlet.html"/></li>
```

The servlet gives back one word:

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("OOps");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

And the result is that my page is truncated directly after the "OOps"

```
    <ul class="navList">
    <li>ICR Open Tasks</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
    <li>OOps
```

The tomcat throws this error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet 
[validateUser] in context with path [/CAS] threw exception
[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data]
with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

I have tried to add and remove the out.flush(); and out.close(); as well as added flush="true" to the jsp:include tag.

I running tomcat 8.0.24; Netbeans with spring MVC.

Edit: It is kind of similar to this [reported bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57476), but that one was fixed in tomcat version 8.0.18 onward. I will run the code tomorrow at work from a glassfish server to see if it is a server issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the HttpServletResponse in the servlet prevents the JSP page from writing to the response. The try with resources block will close the HttpServletResponse on completion too.

Use an ordinary try statement and don't close the response.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try tomorrow as soon as I am back at work.

Comment: Yup, I removed the try with resource, and the close(), and that made it work. Thank you!